# How to erase paint with finger on Image?

Tags: android, paint

Can any body tell me to erase the paint on the image , in my application i was prepared the finger painting on image, if i want erase the paint it,s getting black color on image instead of erasing the image. my code is

```
    public class MyView extends View {
    int bh = originalBitmap.getHeight();
    int bw = originalBitmap.getWidth();
    public MyView(Context c)  {
        super(c);
        //mBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmap,bw,bh,true);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bw,bh,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        mBitmapPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC));
    }
    public MyView (Context c, int color)  {  
        super(c);

        mBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmap,bw,bh,true);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        mBitmapPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC)) ;
        mCanvas.drawColor(color);
    } 
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);           
            /*mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);*/
    }
    @Override 
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {   
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }
```

for paint erase

```
 mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
```

Comment: you want eraser functionality same as Eraser in msPaint in window os?

Comment: see this:http://dl.dropbox.com/u/38493970/Image-4724.jpg i want erase only red color on the image instead of erasing red, it's getting black color.

Comment: How do you erase the color. on what event?

Comment: in the code having menu button's(colorchange , erase) when i wnt to erase (press erase button) i will enter into erase by using finger it will be erase, instead of erasing it shows black color (i  think it erase's background image also).

Comment: I am having a view on which I am drawing using diff-2 colors but when i select eraser it sets the touched area to black. this is the case in 2.3 of android. It would be appreciable if you help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should draw on a transparent custom view placed over the original bitmap instead of modifying the orignal. That will keep it simple. 
For that you can do

```
<RelativeLayout ....>
      <ImageView ......set original bitmap to this/>
      <CustomView ...... draw on this, you can erase too./>
</RelativeLayout>
```

For getting the modified bitmap call the `getDrawingCache()` method on that `RelativeLayout`. That will give you the combined bitmap image.

Hope this helps.

Comment: please tell me how to do that , i am new to this.

Comment: at the time of drawing on emulator it's ok , problem after saving. paint mismatch.

Comment: Do you have scroll and draw option for image? Load the image to fit the screen.

Comment: for image i have OnTouchListener(); in that Zoom, panning, drag.

Comment: You can add this as another question.. As the original question is solved.

Comment: I have been having the same trouble.  I tried the transparent canvas but can't get the eraser function to work that way either.  If you were able to get this to work, would you mind sharing some of your code on how you did it?

Comment: @Anshuman .. I did not write code for this. Its only a concept that Im aware of.

Answer (score 0):

define a temporary bitmap and canvas, then draw canvas on that temporary bitmap and pass that bitmap to onDraw your work will be done,